# Don't show any content and article after migration in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

Sir,
     I upgrade my current joomla 1.5.14 site to 1.5.26 latest version. It has done successfully. After that i migrate this site in joomla 2.5 with redmigrator. Migrate has been done but now no content and article show in my mirated joomla 2.5 site. I migrate site in localhost.
     Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your component can migrate data from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5, not your template. So just look around the template files - check first in your backend whether you've got all data or not. If yes, then go for the template.